# Object id in Django url

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I have a Post model like the one below:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    picturefile = models.ImageField(upload_to="post_content", blank=True)
```

I want to be able to put the id of each post in an url so I can visit each post individually. I did this before with the id of a user and was able to view the user's profile page.

```
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', Dashviews.public_profile_view, name='public_profile_view'),
```

But how do I make the same type of url, with an id of a post?

Comment: That's basically what the Django tutorial is about.

Answer (score 7):

Simply

```
url('^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$',Dashviews.public_post_view, name='public_post_view'),
```

in `views.py`:

```
def public_post_view(request, post_id):
    # do some stuff
```

in templates:

```
{% url 'public_post_view' post.id %}
```

Comment: this returns: the view got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_id'

Comment: @Acework I guess you need to define your function as def public_post_view(request, post_id)

Answer (score 3):

A better way to that is by adding a get_absolute_url to the model:

First, define your view for the model:

```
def public_post_view(request, post_id):
    # print(post_id) or whatever you want
```

Then create the url to map that view:

urls.py

```
url('^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', Dashviews.public_post_view, name='public_post_view'),
```

Then, make every object in your Post model able to create its own url.

models.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    picturefile = models.ImageField(upload_to="post_content", blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('public_post_view', kwargs={'post_id': self.id})
```

Now you're able to just use

```
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">Go to the post</a>
```

in your templates. So whenever you're displaying something like `{{ post.content }}` or stuff like that, you can also use the get_absolute_url method to get its URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', Dashviews.public_profile_view, name='public_profile_view'),
```